# Listview with images saved on the sdcard gets so slow

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I have an application that takes images from the camera, then store them in a folder and path is stored in the SQLite database subsequently be displayed in a Listview, but when i scrolling, the ListView moves very slow.

Android monitor shows me the following message

> The application can do too much work on your main thread.

I've read that doing a AsyncTask the problem is solved, I would like to know how to get the path of the images using AsyncTask.

Here is my code

```
public class PropiedadCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private PropiedadDbAdapter dbAdapter =null;

public PropiedadCursorAdapter (Context context,  Cursor c){
    super(context, c);
    dbAdapter = new PropiedadDbAdapter(context);
    dbAdapter.abrir();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view =((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_propiedades,parent,false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.ivCasa = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivCasa);
    holder.tvTitulo= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
    holder.tvUbicacion= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ubicacion);

    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivCasa;
    TextView tvTitulo;
    TextView tvUbicacion;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String cadena = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_IMAGENES));
    Picasso.with(context).load(cadena).into(holder.ivCasa);

    holder.tvUbicacion.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION)));
    holder.tvTitulo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_TITULO)));
}}
```

Here is my AsyncTask

```
public class getImageTask extends AsyncTask<PropiedadCursorAdapter.ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap> {

private PropiedadCursorAdapter.ViewHolder v;


@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(PropiedadCursorAdapter.ViewHolder... params) {
    v = params[0];
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    String cadena = PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_IMAGENES; 

} }
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you get the path without?

Comment: ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); String cadena = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_IMAGENES)); Picasso.with(context).load(cadena).into(holder.ivCasa);

Comment: I don't know how to do it .

Comment: `I would like to know how to get the path of the images using AsyncTask.` ???? If you can get the path without an async task then what is the problem if you use one? You were asked that before.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it in an AsyncTask, what shoul i put in the method onPostExecute() ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not go in the Adapter in bindView data acquisition, but should request complete data initialization, and then stored in a package of Bean, and then set to Adapter, so the speed will be much faster.